# PHP: using MySQL connections in singleton class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a PHP web service that uses a singleton API class to call my web service methods. I have specific classes for each module in my application: Posts, Users, Login, etc. My API class is something like:

```
class API{

    private static $api;
    private $database;
    private $post;
    private $user;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->database = new DataBase();
        $this->post = new Post();
        $this->user = new User();
    }

    public static function getInstance(){
        if(empty(self::$api)){
            self::$api = new API();
        }
        return self::$api;
    }
}
```

So, to get my user posts, I'd call `$api->post->getPosts()` inside the API class, or `API::getPosts()` outside the API class. The API class is a facade. Each child class has its own `DataBase` instance. For example, `Post` and `User` has the following:

```
class User{
    private $database;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->database = new DataBase();
    }
}
```

My `DataBase` constructor is something like:

```
public function __construct() {
    try{
        $this->db = new \PDO(
                "mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->base;",
                $this->user, $this->pass, 
                array(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'")
        );
    }catch(\PDOException $e){
        echo "<b>Error:</b> {$e->getMessage()} in <b>{$e->getFile()}</b> on line <b>{$e->getLine()}</b>";
        die();
    }
}
```

The problem is: **each request uses up to five MySQL connections to generate the response**. For example: a regular request includes login validation, get user info, get posts info, etc. I was wondering if I can pass the `DataBase` instance from the `API` facade to the children classes. I tried something like:

```
public static function getDatabase(){
    $api = self::getInstance();
    return $api->database;
}
```

But every time I call `API::getDatabase()` from the children classes, I get a MySQL *TOO MANY CONNECTIONS* error, because this method calls the API `__construct()` and creates a new `DataBase` instance.

Any idea how can I recycle my `DataBase` instance, or connections, to avoid connections wasting?

---

**UPDATE**

As suggested bellow, I used the *dependency injection pattern* to pass my `DataBase` object from the API facade to its children:

```
    public function __construct(){
        $this->database = new DataBase();
        $this->post = new Post($this->database);
        $this->user = new User($this->database);
    }
```

Comment: you're already using a singleton in the one class. why not make your DB connection a singleton as well? There's rarely a reason to open a connection to the DB each time you do a db operation. The only two usual excuses are connecting to entirely different db servers, or connecting with different credentials.

Comment: @MarcB Would a singleton `DataBase` class decrease my requests performance? I'll explain, I read that PHP and MySQL handle all the requests in a single thread. So, using a singleton `DataBase` class will create a request queue, where each query should wait for the previous to run.

Comment: database calls block, and PHP isn't multithreaded.

Comment: @MarcB So, your advice is: create a singleton `DataBase` class?

Comment: You should strongly think about dependency injection. Singletons are a nice educational exercise, but offer little value in terms of making your code more loosely coupled. Also, you don't really have a singleton here.  You need to make the constructor private to ensure the only way to instantiate is via static method.

Comment: Don't use singletons. Use proper dependency injection: pass an instance of `Database` to `User`'s and `Post`'s constructors.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I've implemented the dependency injection, passing the `DataBase` object as a parameter to the children classes. I'll test the performance.

Comment: @MikeBrant Post you comment as an answer, and I'll accept it. Dependency Injection pattern worked very well here. Thanks!

Comment: @drux It doesn't really answer the question though.  You might consider answering your own question here with specifics on your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(To take this out of "Unanswered".)

The commenters suggested and the OP verified:

Use the dependency injection pattern to pass the DataBase object from the API facade to its children:

```
private function __construct(){
    $this->database = new DataBase();
    $this->post = new Post($this->database);
    $this->user = new User($this->database);
}
```

(Actually `private` was suggested but not confirmed.)